# How to make nfs-kernel-server.service initialise when the only NFS exports are ZFS?

Tags: debian, nfs, zfs

I have a number of ZFS file systems intended to be exported:

```
$ sudo zfs get sharenfs
NAME                              PROPERTY  VALUE                SOURCE
zpool0                            sharenfs  off                  local
zpool0/books                      sharenfs  rw=@192.168.15.0/24  local
zpool0/music                      sharenfs  rw=@192.168.15.0/24  local
zpool0/photo                      sharenfs  rw=@192.168.15.0/24  local
zpool0/video                      sharenfs  rw=@192.168.15.0/24  local
[...]
```

These are the only file systems intended to be exported via NFS, so they are not listed in `/etc/exports`:

```
$ grep -v '^#' <  /etc/exports  | wc -c
0
```

Unfortunately this seems to mean that the nfs kernel service won't register the various RPC services needed for the ZFS system to export the relevant file systems:

```
$ sudo systemctl status  nfs-kernel-server.service 
● nfs-kernel-server.service - LSB: Kernel NFS server support
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/nfs-kernel-server)
   Active: active (exited) since Sun 2017-06-25 13:18:48 IST; 10h ago
  Process: 3867 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/nfs-kernel-server start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Jun 25 13:18:48 jupiter nfs-kernel-server[3867]: \\
Not starting NFS kernel daemon: no exports. ... (warning).
Jun 25 13:18:48 jupiter systemd[1]: Started LSB: Kernel NFS server support.
```

(I added a line break at the point marked with `\\` so that the relevant message would be clearly shown).

As a result the needed RPC services are not registered:

```
$ /usr/sbin/rpcinfo -p localhost
program vers proto   port  service
100000    4   tcp    111  portmapper
100000    3   tcp    111  portmapper
100000    2   tcp    111  portmapper
100000    4   udp    111  portmapper
100000    3   udp    111  portmapper
100000    2   udp    111  portmapper
100024    1   udp  60457  status
100024    1   tcp  55306  status
```

Notice that for example the mount and stat services are not registered.   Hence ZFS cannot export its own file systems.

I'm seeing this problem on Debian version 8.8:

```
$ dpkg -l nfs-kernel-server zfsutils-linux
[...]
ii  nfs-kernel-server                              1:1.2.8-9                    amd64                        support for NFS kernel server
ii  zfsutils-linux                                 0.6.5.9-2~bpo8+1             amd64                        command-line tools to manage OpenZFS filesystems
```

This did used to work, but since I reboot the NFS server very rarely it's possible that when I last booted it there was some entry in `/etc/exports` which would have prevented this problem.

I believe I have correctly set ZFS up to export the filesystems:

```
$ grep -B2 ZFS_SHARE   /etc/default/zfs 
# Run `zfs share -a` during system start?
# nb: The shareiscsi, sharenfs, and sharesmb dataset properties.
ZFS_SHARE='yes'
```

Any ideas how I can solve this?   I could hand-hack this conditional in `/etc/init.d/nfs-kernel-server`...

```
if [ -f /etc/exports ] && grep -q '^[[:space:]]*[^#]*/' $export_files
then
    do_modprobe nfsd
```

... but that seems inelegant and likely to be reversed by future updates.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After re-reading [Aaron Toponce's excellent guide](https://pthree.org/2012/12/31/zfs-administration-part-xv-iscsi-nfs-and-samba/) I believe the best workaround is to put a dummy export in `/etc/exports` as he describes [here](https://pthree.org/2012/12/31/zfs-administration-part-xv-iscsi-nfs-and-samba/):

```
$ echo '/mnt localhost(ro)' >> /etc/exports
$ sudo /etc/init.d/nfs-kernel-server start
$ showmount -e hostname.example.com
Export list for hostname.example.com:
/mnt localhost
```

Notice above that we edit `/etc/exports` by redirection, so presumably must be running as root, despite the `$` shell prompt.